# Rearrange columns in python pandas: putting last column in the middle

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with 105 columns.I want to bring the last column in the middle of a dataframe.How can i achieve that.

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 col11 col12 col13 col14 col15
```

The output should look like

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col15 col8 col9 col10 col11 col12 col13 col14

df.iloc[:,list(range(7))+ [-1]]
```

The above code works for the first 7 cols and the last column but i got stuck on how to get the remaining column

Answer (score 3):

#### `pop` + `insert`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({f'c{i}': [i] for i in range(1,16)})

cname = df.columns[-1]
df.insert(int(len(df.columns)/2), cname, df.pop(cname))

print(df)
#   c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c15  c8  c9  c10  c11  c12  c13  c14
#0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   15   8   9   10   11   12   13   14
```

---

#### `np.r_`

You create a list of the .iloc indices to slice with. There's a bit of math to deal with whether there are an even or odd number of columns.

```
N = int(len(df.columns)/2)
r = len(df.columns)%2
idx = np.r_[0:N, -1, -N-r:-1]
#array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6, -1, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2])

df = df.iloc[:, idx]
#   c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c15  c8  c9  c10  c11  c12  c13  c14
#0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   15   8   9   10   11   12   13   14
```

Answer (score 3):

One with index union:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(16)).add_prefix('col')

mid = len(df.columns)//2
idx = df.columns[:mid].union(df.columns[[-1]]
                      .union(df.columns[mid:-1],sort=False),sort=False)
out = df[idx]
```

---

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col0, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, 
         col15, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14]
Index: []
```